# Understanding Flash Packages

Tags: flash, flex4, prefuse

I'm trying to understand how packages and dependencies work with Adobe Flash Builder 4.

I've copied an example [here](http://flare.prefuse.org/src/flare.apps/src/flare/apps/DependencyGraph.as) and put it in a .as file called DependencyGraph.

However I get the error message:

```
A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '', 
as the definition's package, 'DependencyGraph'.
```

I understand that the original file has a package name called `package flare.apps`. What should I change to enable this to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the file in the correct directory, in your case:

```
flare/apps/DependencyGraph.as
```